# Django ModuleNotFoundError when adding app

Tags: python, django

I'm using Visual Studio with Python tools to develop my Django project. I've create an app through the IDE. However after adding the app into the INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py, it is always giving me ModuleNotFound Error

This is the directory structure.

[image]

This is how I've added the app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'kleis',
]
```

Stacktrace

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000228FCA30A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Exceptions\Projects\Kleis\Backend Django\Server\Server\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kleis'
```

Comment: in the `INSTALLED_APPS ` try `server. kleis` instead of `kleis` and see if it works.

Comment: @NihalSharma Yes it works. Can I know why I need the Server infront? Most tutorial i read online only needs the app name

Comment: It's because of your directory structure and the relative path of your settings file to the module. Try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project for a clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the above solutions but didnt get solved either.
If we miss to import the path in the newly created urls.py we will be seeing this error,
from django.urls import path (refer:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)
this will solve this error
Good Luck